# Load local file in Chrome App Webview implementation

Tags: google-chrome, webview

I tried Marc Rochkind's suggestion for [loading a local file via a chrome app webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23374184/load-local-file-in-chrome-app-webview), and I couldn't get it to work.

When I tried with an mhtml page, the webview doesn't render the local page, and the page gets slow. No errors.

Then I tried with a small picture file and the webview element is removed and replaced with this:

```
<pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;">‰PNG

���
IHDR������0���}jž���sBIT|dˆ���  pHYs�����šœ���îIDATX…í×½JÃP€á'µ-EQ,8é&amp;^¢7¡›.Š£“Aœ\trï :xuð$„’Ô§ï…oÉÏyg„Ÿ¶q‚)f™fŠSì$Ã.&gt;2ÕùÄ\tˆ”sUàcÝöU$±ózÿP@P@P@·4­kóçö‚­4¯-ßmüà36mpœ®e…ž°^sé^è«õ§ÖðøWèËs²Ü/
]cÔ�)á¦-4Á°R6ÄeSèý²~Zc.t&amp;Ï×¢—Öª…ŽPd@Ê
W¡ƒŒ@µCÌ–0À~‡Ð-ß­eàbÖßÕq����IEND®B`‚</pre>
```

No idea why it did that.

My related code is below, and you can see an example of the readAsDataUrl function [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader.readAsDataURL).

main.js, my app event page. It just take the file, and passes the data url to an app window.

```
chrome.storage.local.get('directory_ref', function(items) { 
  var ref = items.directory_ref;

  chrome.fileSystem.restoreEntry(ref, function(storage) {
    var fileName = 'test.html';

    storage.getFile(fileName, { create: false }, function(fileEntry) {
      fileEntry.file(function(file) {

        var fileReader = new FileReader();

        fileReader.onloadend = function() {
          var dataUrl = fileReader.result;

          chrome.app.window.create('webview_demo.html', function(window) {
            window.dataUrl = dataUrl;
          });
        };

        fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);
      });
    });
  });
});
```

webview_demo.html

```
<script src="webview.js"></script>

<webview id="webview" src=""></webview>
```

webview.js

```
var dataUrl = chrome.app.window.current().dataUrl,
    webview = document.getElementById('webview');

webview.src = dataUrl;
```

Any suggestions or flaws that you see in my method would be helpful.

Comment: It looks like the png is being loaded as binary, I'd log "var dataUrl" in webview.js and see if looks like a legit data URI: e.g. "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgo...."

Comment: I've tried similar simpler approach and that works: https://github.com/lazyboy/chromium/tree/master/tests/chrome-apps/webview_dataurl_from_background, not sure what's happening in your case. It's harder to guess cause you've a simplified snippet, which seems incomplete, e.g. 1) you're reading a file named test.html, what does that file contain? 2) your webview_demo.html seems to load the script first but defines the <webview> element afterwards, so webview.js wouldn't even see the element, etc. So maybe providing more context is helpful. Ty.

Comment: is there any extension in chrome who does this job?